# migration from mariadb to mysql 5.7 created password reset and column count issues

Tags: mysql, linux, database

we uninstall mariadb from my fedora machine and install mysql 5.7 community server , after installation everything was fine but we run mysql_upgrade --force -uUser -p unknowingly.

now i am not able to do anything with my database. Please help , the below are some error appearing.

mysql> use mysql;
ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.

mysql> SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('root');
ERROR 1805 (HY000): Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 45, found 46. The table is probably corrupted

mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret';
ERROR 1805 (HY000): Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 45, found 46. The table is probably corrupted

Comment: Have you done `mysql_secure_installation`? or you logged into mysql prompt without password?

Comment: This might be useful https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/mysql/issues/410

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem.
This is how I solved it.

```
    service mysql stop
    mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
    mysql
    # Delete the extra column
    ALTER TABLE mysql.user DROP COLUMN is_role;
    # Update your password
    ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';
    flush privileges;
    quit
```

Now, you are able to run command `mysql_upgrade -uroot -p` to upgrade your database.
After doing these,  restart your mysql server process back into a normal mode.
Problem solved.

Comment: Good tip - `ALTER TABLE mysql.user DROP COLUMN is_role;` did the trick for me.

Comment: when i run `mysql` it throws `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)` can you pls help.